# how to add a property to a component that will reflect on the object inspector

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-7

in Delphi 7 , when adding a propery to an object, how is it possible to see that property in the object inspector?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Make the property `published`. For instance,

```
private
  FMyProperty: integer;
published
  property MyProperty: integer read FMyProperty write FMyProperty;
```

Often, you need to repaint the control (or do some other processing) when a property is changed. Then you can do

```
private
  FMyProperty: integer;
  procedure SetMyProperty(MyProperty: integer);
published
  property MyProperty: integer read FMyProperty write SetMyProperty;

...

procedure TMyControl.SetMyProperty(MyProperty: integer);
begin
  if FMyProperty <> MyProperty then
  begin
    FMyProperty := MyProperty;
    Invalidate; // for example
  end;
end;
```

Comment: @jachguate: I know. It isn't easy to beat me! :)

Comment: `Repaint` seems a bit heavy. Aren't you meant to call `Invalidate` and wait for the next paint cycle to come around in the natural way.

Comment: @David: Yes, that is most often what you would do.

Answer (score 4):

Add that property to the published section, it will make it appear on the Object Inspector, like this:

```
TMyComponent = class(TComponent)
 ...
published
  property MyProperty: string read FMyProperty write SetMyProperty;
```

Answer (score 3):

From the [docs](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/radstudio2007/RS2007_helpupdates/HUpdate4/EN/html/devwin32/cwgpropertydeclaration_xml.html):

> Properties declared in a published
>   section of the component's class
>   declaration are editable in the Object
>   Inspector at design time.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget that the Component needs to get registered within Delphi (preferable in a Design Time Package) or you you won't see anything in the Object Inspector at all !!!

I mean ... I can create a new TPanel descendant called TMyPanel and add a new Published property to it :

```
type
  TPanel1 = class(TPanel)
  private
    FMyName: String;
    { Private declarations }
  protected
    { Protected declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  published
    { Published declarations }
    property MyName : String read FMyName write FMyName;
  end;
```

but that property won't get displayed in the Object Inspector if you havn't registered the new class using RegisterComponent :

```
procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('Samples', [TPanel1]);
end;
```

Just to be complete :-)